# A little confused about MVC and where to put a database query

Tags: joomla

OK, so my Joomla app is in MVC format.  I am still a little confused about where to put certain operations, in the Controller or in the Model.  This function below is in the controller, it gets called when `&task=remove`. Should the database stuff be in the Model?  It does not seem to fit there because I have two models **editapp** (display a single application) and **allapps** (display all the applications), now which one would I put the delete operation in?

```
    /**
 * Delete an application
 */
function remove() {
    global $mainframe;

    $cid = JRequest::getVar( 'cid', array(), '', 'array' );
    $db =& JFactory::getDBO();

    //if there are items to delete
    if(count($cid)){
        $cids = implode( ',', $cid );
        $query = "DELETE FROM #__myapp_apps WHERE id IN ( $cids )";
        $db->setQuery( $query );

        if (!$db->query()){
            echo "<script> alert('".$db->getErrorMsg()."');window.history.go(-1); </script>\n";
        }
    }

    $mainframe->redirect( 'index.php?option=' . $option . '&c=apps');
}
```

I am also confused about how the flow works.  For example, there is a display() function in the controller that gets called by default.  If I pass a task, does the display() function still run or does it go directly to the function name passed by $task?

Comment: Regarding your comment on my answer, you were very right. I stupidly answered without considering that the pattern might differ in Joomla from what I've seen using other technologies. I've deleted my answer, so that it won't lead anybody astray. If you haven't seen it already, this is a guide on how to create a mvc component in joomla, maybe that can help: http://www.vojtechovsky.net/joomla/component-helloworld-2-create-tutorial-guide-en.html . Sorry about the misinformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to keep all database functionality in your model.  If you don't know which model a method should go in, it's possible that you need to change your models to better reflect your problem.

In your case, though, I think this method would go in allapps since it can handle operations on multiple apps.

If you pass in a task, that method will be called.  If you want to then call the display method, just call it at the end of your edit method.

When in doubt, take a look at the weblinks component's models and controllers.  They are very simple and a good example of how to do MVC in Joomla!.